# Possible to avoid device fingerprinting with imagemagick?

Tags: fingerprinting, image

If I took a picture with my mobile phone and wanted to publish that photo without any artefacts connect to me, the first thing I would do is strip all of the image metadata with 'exiftool':

`exiftool -all= IMG_1234.JPG`

... but it is well understood that even without the exif data, the image size, resolution, compression level, etc., has a lot of identifying information in it that can be tied back to the camera that took it.

What is the optimal why I could break device fingerprinting in a photo after stripping the exif data by processing it in some way with ImageMagick?

A good first start would be to simply resize the image to a random integer percentage:

`magick convert image.jpg -resize 95% image2.jpg`

... and not only would that change the resolution and the image size, but since nothing was changing but the size (we're *not* cropping), presumably the entire compression of the image would also change, perhaps eliminating a lot of identifying compression artefacts?

Is that a big step forward or not much of a step at all?

If simply changing the percentage size of the image is not much of a step towards avoiding device fingerprinting, *what would be*?

What imagemagick transformation - or transformations - would make an image very difficult to tie to a particular camera *or to a particular set of already published photographs*?

Answer (score 3):

Your stated protections are reasonable, however using ML techniques (given a large enough corpus) would likely defeat them. That could be mitigated by introducing some imperceptible randomness to throw off the model, but that in and of itself is a marker. Also, [sensor fingerprinting](https://www.usenix.org/conference/raid2020/presentation/maier) using something like [Camfinger](https://www.phonearena.com/news/Your-phones-camera-has-a-unique-ID-you-never-knew-about_id87786) would still allow someone to uniquely identify photos. I can't find any known ways to subvert that, so ... again, introducing an imperceptible random mask (least-significant-bit perhaps?) may be effective.

To directly answer your questions: the random cropping does distort compression and therefore remove that vector of identification, exifdata removal is necessary, and given a motivated enough attacker (for example, The Government) there are too many hardware markers to fingerprint a device that removing all of them is futile or at least very difficult without damaging the image.